# Is there a way to stop clang-format from putting space after return?

Tags: c++, clang-format

If I have something like this:

```
bool someFunction()
{
    return(true);
}
```

and pass it through clang-format, it always adds a space between the return and opening ( like this:

```
bool someFunction()
{
    return (true);
}
```

I've got SpaceBeforeParens set to Never yet it still adds this space. Does anybody know of a way to control this?

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: unrelated advice: stop using parenthesis around return values ,because when you start using auto as deduced return values this will return a reference instead of the value you probably want.

Answer (score -1):

stop using parenthesis around return values ,because when you start using auto as deduced return values this will return a reference to the value (most likely not what you want) instead of the value you probably want.

And your issue immediately disappears.

Comment: Funny how 2 people up-voted an answer that does not address the actual question. I have the same problem I want to resolve but in my case I'm trying to not add an extra space to a code like `if(condition){foo();}` - how does your "solution" help me? :(

Comment: Most companies have a coding standard that requires the parentheses to avoid ambiguity. It is best to be explicit in what you want returned, especially in C

Comment: @Nfettinger: about C ,well the question is flagged C++ so C is not considered especially since I mentioned "deduced" (does C have type deducing?).

Comment: @Nfettinger: standards and guidelines are a good thing ,but when they're changing the meaning of code then they must not become dogmatic.